# How to choose the best answer in puzzles?

Tags: puzzle-creation, puzzle-theory

I gave my friends a lateral thinking puzzle

> There are six eggs in the basket. Six people each take one of the eggs. How can it be that one egg is left in the basket?

My intended answer was

> One of them put the egg again inside the basket.

But one of my friend answered

> The last person took the basket with the last egg still inside.

Clearly my friend's answer is more creative then my own (as lateral thinking puzzle demands). Now I am confused if I should take his answer for granted (as I should because I found his answer more creative) or should I say that his answer is wrong just because it was not my intended answer?

The definition given by [wikipedia on puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle) is: A puzzle is a game, problem, or toy that tests a person's ingenuity or knowledge.

It got to me thinking if puzzles are just to find the intended answer of the question asker or is it to find the most appropriate and reasonable answer. Which one of them would be better? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: why downvote...any reason?

Comment: I like this question and reckon that it belongs here in its general sense. It also belongs at Meta Puzzling in the sense specific to this site. And there it almost is: [Meta Puzzling -- My puzzle was answered credibly: correctly but not as intended](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2879/18129)

Comment: Why is it agreed upon here but this [question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27686/make-82-with-numbers-and-dots) had the same issue, and yet the comment " what do you mean? You know you don't get to say but that's not the answer I had in my head, try again!, right? If someone finds a solution to your riddle/puzzle, mark it as solved. Otherwise, we close it for being too broad. – user1717828 " Is clearly a false (blackmailing) statement though no one cares that it pressured the OP into accepting an answer he didn't intend as the solution.

Comment: @Daedric I am considering more polite (not blackmailing) and general case here. I just want to know if puzzle only needs to be solved according to the one who asked the question or puzzle is something that finds the fast, most suitable and reasonable answer.

Comment: @manshu I didn't say he did the right thing, he is out of line and should be spoken to by a mod, he can't make up rules like that, or claim that is how we do things here. I think if the OP didn't plan for another answer then its is absolutely fine for them to narrow down their answer, as long as they state that clearly in the question.

Comment: @Daedric I understand.

Comment: I would acknowledge that it is a fault in the puzzle that there is more than one equally credible solution then revise the puzzle iteratively to exclude the less pleasing solution in future.

Comment: @MartinSmith Does it mean that I should get my intended answer by putting many limits in the situation? I don't think that lateral thinking puzzles are a kind of puzzle which should molded once all the conditions are given. (I personally think that this should be applied to all kind of puzzles)

Comment: Your puzzle also doesn't exclude the situation that one of the egg takers takes the egg from an earlier recipient. I prefer puzzles with a single "correct" answer.

Comment: @manshu OK, misunderstood, thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>(Not a guess at any specific answer that the question's poser had in mind.)</sup>

#### Premise

The more the merrier.
 
Different solutions have different virtues.
Eventually every solution will be appreciated
by some puzzle lover.

#### Solutions have a variety of virtues

Far from being exhaustive or mutually exclusive,
these qualities are
listed alphabetically
within two broad categories.
Edits welcome.

More for sport:

  •  approval

  •  brevity

  •  creativity / inventiveness / originality

  •  esoterica / sophistication

  •  firstness

  •     <del>humor</del> 
                              <del>**humour**</del> 
                                          **mirth**

  •  obviousness

  •  simplicity / ease of calculation

  •  subtlety

> •  surprise

More for the long term:

  •  clarity

  •  completeness

  •  education / cross reference

  •  generality

  •  resourcefulness

  •  variety, the spice of life

#### Brief case study of the kind of puzzle in question

[Relabeling two 20-sided dice without changing their
 total](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25832/18129)

This puzzle received a wonderful solution that was accepted by the poser,
who then proceeded to present the intended solution
so that it wouldn't be overlooked.

Three solutions have been posted to date, each with its virtues.

1. [A complete solution that transforms the puzzle into
   algebra](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/25834/18129)

   This solution is so complete, educational, general and sophisticated,
   who could ask for more?
2. [An old-fashioned solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/25835/18129)

   This detective-like solution does not require the mathematics
   or computer employed by the complete solution.
   Then again, only one of several possible solutions is found
   and a general solution is only alluded to.
3. [The poser's inventive
   solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/25889/18129)

   Quite possibly the poser all along had subconsciously hoped that
   nobody else would actually think of this gem of an approach,
   one that even adds to the understanding of the other solutions.

#### Conclusion

The more the merrier.
 
As in the case study:
a puzzle's creator can acknowledge an unintended excellent solution,
someone else can provide an incomplete solution for a different audience,
and the poser can present their original solution for posterity
and still blow our minds.

---

#### Corollary

Some unexpected solutions simply deserve their own puzzles.
 
The original puzzle (P)
may be restated as two different puzzles
tailored differently for the originally intended solution (S)
and for the unexpected one (S2).

> **P 🡒 P1.**  
>    There are six eggs  <del>in the basket</del> 
>    **on a shelf**.
>    Six people each take one of the eggs.
>    How can it be that one egg is left  <del>in the basket</del> 
>    **on the shelf**?

> **S 🡒 S1.**  
>  One of them put the egg again  <del>inside the basket</del> 
>  **on the shelf**.
>  
>         
>  (Presumably a person cannot take the shelf,
>   or occupy it while holding their egg.)

[Chaotic’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/27747/18129)
provides a way to restate part of the puzzle
so as to exclude the intended solution.

> **P 🡒 P2.**  
>    There are six eggs in the basket.
>    Six people each take one of the eggs
>    **and nobody put it again in the basket.**
>    How can it be that one egg is left in the basket?

> **S2.**  
>  The last person took the basket with the last egg still inside.

**Examples of solutions that earned their own puzzles**

- [Gareth McCaughan’s
  solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49157/18129)
  (S2) received its own puzzle,
  [*Unreflected infinitely simple polygon reflexivity*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49151/unreflected-infinitely-simple-polygon-reflexivity) (P2),
  because it was brilliantly different from,
  even if not technically better than,
  [the intended
  solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50724/18129) (S/S1)
  to the puzzle restated as
  [*Infinitely simple polygon solipsism*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49207/infinitely-simple-polygon-solipsism) (P1).
- [boboquack’s
  solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51783/18129)
  (S2) at
  [*New Mathematics forever*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51782/new-mathematics-forever) (P2)
  was an unforeseen superior solution to
  the original statement of the puzzle reincarnated as
  [*If 6 was 9, or 100 was 64, or M was N*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51932/if-6-was-9-or-100-was-64-or-m-was-n) (P1).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose it was the *opposite*: you had the most creative answer, and your friend gave the less creative answer. Then you could:

> Clarify your question by saying that six people each took one of the eggs and nobody put it again in the basket.

This way you narrowed the answers to the right one, which is also the most creative one.

I think this is a matter of opinion, but I'm in favor of the *most creative answer* no matter what, specially for lateral thinking puzzles. So if your question admits more than one answer, you should accept the more creative one.