# New Mathematics forever

Tags: formation-of-numbers

<sup>**This has been (renamed and) refocused on
  [boboquack’s
   unforeseen solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51783/18129),
  which deserves its own puzzle.**</sup>

<sup>Right when you thought the good old days of
[New Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Math)
were safely
[dusted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leave_someone%2Fsomething_in_the_dust),
along comes an unending lesson on similarities of
[numbers in different bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix).
For this  <del>lesson</del>  puzzle,
**100<sub>8</sub>** means the digits **100** in
[base 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal),
which equals the familiar 64
(in [base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)),
which itself is represented as **64<sub>10</sub>**.</sup>

Just when is 100 the same as 64?
 
When *isn’t* it?!
 
Just look:

100<sub>8</sub>    =  64<sub>**10**</sub>
?   **✓**


         
  100<sub>**10**</sub>      =  64<sub>**16**</sub>
?   **✓**


         
  100<sub>**16**</sub>      =  64<sub>42</sub>
?   **✓**
    Could this go on forever?

That used **6** different digits in
all — 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8 — and
may be summarißed as...

K  <sub>W</sub>      =  L <sub>**X**</sub>


          
 K <sub>**X**</sub>     =  L <sub>**Y**</sub>


          
 K <sub>**Y**</sub>   =  L <sub>Z</sub>

...where   K = 100,
           L = 64,
           W = 8,
           X = 10,
           Y = 16   and
           Z = 42.

And no, this pattern does not continue forever,
not even past
L <sub>Z</sub> ( 64<sub>42</sub> ).

> But wait,  other patterns can indeed go on forever.
>    
>   And with fewer different digits.
>
> M <sub>P</sub>     =  N <sub>**Q**</sub>
>   
>
>           
>    M <sub>**Q**</sub>        =  N <sub>**R**</sub>
>   
>
>           
>    M <sub>**R**</sub>          =  N <sub>**S**</sub>
>   
>
>           
>    M <sub>**S**</sub>   =  N <sub>**T**</sub>
>   
>            
>    **.**
>   
>            
>    **.**
>   
>            
>    **.**
>
> **What pattern of M, N, P, Q, R, S, T,  .  .  .  
>     uses the fewest different digits?**
>
> How can that be generalized to other numbers of different digits?
>
> ( M > N   and  
>     P < Q < R < S < T <   **· · ·** )

To quote professor Tom Lehrer from
[*New Math* <sub><sub>YouTube</sub></sub>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HkLsfa67mA),
“Hooray for New Math!”

Comment: Is "summarißed" a typo or intentional?

Comment: "Summarißed" is just an attempt to spell both/neither UKish and/nor USAish ("ß" = "s/z"; someday unicodologists will discover a ligature for "o/ou" as well)

Comment: @humn I fear this puzzle is so simple, so very simple, that only a child can do it.

Comment: (To anyone feeling like I'm insulting @humn for making a bad puzzle or them for not solving it instantly: please follow that YouTube link.)

Comment: The originally intended puzzle will be re-posed in a way that better distinguishes the originally intended solution

Comment: The puzzle originally intended here has been re-posed as [_If 6 was 9, or 100 was 64, or M was N_](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51932/if-6-was-9-or-100-was-64-or-m-was-n)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little touch-up to the previous answer gives a proper solution:

> I doubt you can do it with just one digit, but feel free to prove me wrong!
>  \begin{array}{lcl}100_{10}&=&10_{100}\\100_{100}&=&10_{10000}\\100_{10000}&=&10_{100000000}\\100_{100000000}&=&10_{10000000000000000}\\&\vdots&\end{array}
>  \begin{array}{lcl}200_{10}&=&20_{100}\\200_{100}&=&20_{10000}\\200_{10000}&=&20_{100000000}\\200_{100000000}&=&20_{10000000000000000}\\&\vdots&\end{array}
>  \begin{array}{lcl}203_{10}&=&23_{100}\\203_{100}&=&23_{10000}\\203_{10000}&=&23_{100000000}\\203_{100000000}&=&23_{10000000000000000}\\&\vdots&\end{array}
>  Note: the pattern really begins here:
>  \begin{array}{lcl}40203_{10}&=&423_{100}\\40203_{100}&=&423_{10000}\\40203_{10000}&=&423_{100000000}\\40203_{100000000}&=&423_{10000000000000000}\\&\vdots&\end{array}
>  \begin{array}{lcl}5040203_{10}&=&5423_{100}\\5040203_{100}&=&5423_{10000}\\5040203_{10000}&=&5423_{100000000}\\5040203_{100000000}&=&5423_{10000000000000000}\\&\vdots&\end{array}
>  \begin{array}{lcl}605040203_{10}&=&65423_{100}\\605040203_{100}&=&65423_{10000}\\605040203_{10000}&=&65423_{100000000}\\605040203_{100000000}&=&65423_{10000000000000000}\\&\vdots&\end{array}
>  \begin{array}{c}\vdots\end{array}

Comment: And you can even make an infinite chain too!

Comment: (Puzzling should have a badge for solutions that get puzzles refitted to them.)