# If 6 was 9, or 100 was 64, or M was N

Tags: no-computers, formation-of-numbers

***N**ow if a 6,*     
         *Turned out to be 9,* 
         *I don’ t mind,* 
         *I don’ t mind*
  – Jimi Hendrix in *If 6 was 9*

Cool.  Suppose a 100 turned out to be 64.

*I don’ t care,* 
         *I don’ t care*
  – Jimi Hendrix in *If 6 was 9*

But, but Jimi, what if your computer program is bugged out
and can’t tell if its bad self
is coming (from [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal))
or going  (to [hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal))?

100<sub>8</sub>    =  64<sub>**10**</sub>
  

         
  100<sub>**10**</sub>      =  64<sub>**16**</sub>
  

         
  100<sub>**16**</sub>      =  64<sub>42</sub>

*Let it be,*          
         *It ain’ t me*
  – Jimi Hendrix in *If 6 was 9*

You know,
**100<sub>8</sub>** stands for the digits **100** in
[base **8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal),
equaling the familiar
**64** (in [base **10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)),
which itself shows as **64<sub>10</sub>**.

*Dig*
   – Jimi Hendrix in *If 6 was 9*

So, that used
**6 different
  digits** — 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8 — **a
total of 26 times**
and bubbles down to...

K  <sub>W</sub>      =  L <sub>**X**</sub>


        
 K <sub>**X**</sub>     =  L <sub>**Y**</sub>


        
 K <sub>**Y**</sub>   =  L <sub>Z</sub>


        
...where   K = 100,
           L = 64,
           W = 8,
           X = 10,
           Y = 16   and
           Z = 42.

*I’ m gonna wave my freak flag high!*
– Jimi Hendrix in *If 6 was 9*

Hold tight, hitch-hiker,
check out where simpler ingredients can take you.

> Just **4 different digits** from 0 through 9,
>   taken ***fewer than* 43 times total**,
>   can really wig you out.
>
> M <sub>P</sub>     =  N <sub>**Q**</sub>
>       
>    ( M > N   and   P < Q < R < S < T )
>   
>
>           
>    M <sub>**Q**</sub>        =  N <sub>**R**</sub>
>   
>
>           
>    M <sub>**R**</sub>          =  N <sub>**S**</sub>
>   
>
>           
>    M <sub>**S**</sub>   =  N <sub>T</sub>
>
> Wild.
>    
>   **What M, N, P, Q, R, S and T could do that
>     with the *fewest* digits total?**
>
> Even a 43-digits-total solution or two would be worth posting.

*Wave on,*      
         *Wave on . . .*


        
*. . .’ Cause everybody knows what I’ m talking about*


          – Jimi Hendrix in
[*If 6 was 9* <sub>(vocal track)
                  dailymotion</sub>](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3oeta8)

Comment: Computers are in play for calculations, of course,
just not for combinatorial searches.
This puzzle reincarnates the original intention of
[_New Mathematics forever_](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51782/new-mathematics-forever).

Comment: I feel very dumb, but is 100 in base 16 really the same as 64 in base 42?

Comment: $100_{16} = 256_{10}= 6\times 42 + 4$, this time

Comment: :) Thank you, completely my mistake: I was using mods instead of bases... Darn you, new math!

Comment: [It's so simple, so very simple, that only a child can do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXx2VVSWDMo)

Comment: Are the base subscripts always in base-10?

Comment: Also, are we allowed to have digits larger than the base?

Comment: Digits within each base is the intended solution, @2012rcampion, but if you have an end-around, I'd love to ^vote it as much as a feint

Comment: Darn, I just noticed the no-computers tag... I'll just say that my answer has 31 digits ([SHA-256](https://www.google.com/search?q=764488d54b75769d6ba7a191f4cc993c450654ca82919cd1155b987264c1a3b1))

Comment: And why not: here's my original solution with 27 digits: `m=82,n=26,p=1,q=2,r=6,s=22,t=86`.

Comment: (Working on it, @2012rcampion, my original solution has 32 digits. How i love to be allowed on the field of play only to be bested!)

Comment: @humn, why to work  on the previous suggested set of values... they are not technically valid, it seems though !

Comment: The comparisions M >N, and others such as P < Q < R ... happening in numbers of base 10 ..? ;-)

Comment: Yes, @Mea Culpa Nay, all inequalities work out correctly in base 10, even though M and N represent numbers in other bases. (Sorry for the late reply. I love the answer you found!)

Comment: Ps. @2012rcampion, all we need is an explanation for how to find by hand your 31-digit solution (couldn't see it, link didn't work) or 27-digit solution (verified!).

Comment: The link worked fine; I gave a hash of the answer so that I can prove when I found my answer without initially revealing it.  As for how to discover it by hand, I have no clue.

Comment: (Technically not true, but I don't think "try ~10,000,000 sets of `(m,n,p)` by hand" is going to be appreciated.)

Comment: @2012rcampion!  All we need are 10,000,000 hands.
Even then, hand-coding a program is so very close solving by hand.
If you don't mind, I'd like to eventully post a wiki
that includes your amazing 27-total-digits solution
(along with a funny 43-total-digits solution of mine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have a working set, it seems:

> 1011 (base 1)    = 11 (base 2)
>  1011 (base 2)    = 11 (base 10)
>  1011 (base 10)   = 11 (base 1010)
>  1011 (base 1010) = 11 (base 1030302010)

using 4 digits (0,1,2 and 3) and the total number of times those numbers used is - 49 times (well, it was above the 43 limit...) and

assuming fractional bases are valid, here is another one:

> 22 (base 2.25)     = 11 (base 5.5)
>  22 (base 5.5)       = 11 (base 12)
>  22 (base 12)        = 11 (base 25)
>  22 (base 25)        = 11 (base 51 )

using 3 digits (1, 2 and 5) and the total number of times those numbers used is  33.

Here is another one:

> 111 (base 2)     = 21 (base 3)
>  111 (base 3)     = 21 (base 6)
>  111 (base 6)     = 21 (base 21)
>  111 (base 21)     = 21 (base 231)

using *4* digits (1, 2, 3 and 6) and the total number of times those numbers used is  **32**. Hope this satisfies @humn's requirements in all manners.

Comment: "base 1" has (by definition) only one possible digit value, so your first line doesn't work.

Comment: @Rubio what is that possible value Rubio (of base 1 system)?

Comment: I've argued for a long that 0 should be a valid digit in base 1. Would be consistent with all the other bases, including irrational, imaginary and complex.  A 0 at each $n$th place merely adds 0 times $1^n$, while each 1 at each $m$th place adds 1 times $1^m$ as usual.

Comment: I really to love this solution! (Even though uses more digits than called for.)

Comment: Thanks @humn, a nice question (but I guess solution is possible only through brute force / trial and error means only) !

Comment: True that my solutions weren't purely deductive.
They were pretty much intuitive
and involved almost no trial and error.
Plus a little luck, admittedly, which comes with intuition,
upon which I typically rely when doing mathematics.
In any case a bounty is coming for this solution because it
"is neat and pretty, until a phenomenal climactic use of base 1030302010 !" I'm guessing that you used some intuition and luck, too Mea Culpa Nay.

Comment: "Base 1" is in effect a tally system, with 1 usually chosen as the digit to use.  1 is "1", 2 is "11", 3 is "111", and so on.  Cnsider the usual meaning of Base N: each position in a number, right to left, is an increasing power of N, with N distinct digits in use; base 10 has digits 0..9, and positions (right to left) of 10⁰ (ones), 10¹ (tens), 10² (hundreds), and so on.  Base 1 should thus have just a single digit, and position values 1⁰, 1¹, 1², … — all of which equal 1, so you end up representing a value V as a sequence of V 1's. (0 skips a digit position; no need/use for that in Base 1.)

Comment: Nice comparison to Roman numerals, @Rubio!

Comment: I just reviewed my two 43-total-digits solutions, Mea Culpa Nay,
and now actually claim they were honestly derived
from a familiarity with powers of 5.
One of them, which I might post as a wiki, uses a fractional base that
you might enjoy as much as I enjoy your use of base 1030302010.
(My alas-not-optimal 32-total-digits solution, though,
remains a matter of intuition and luck,
but more power to anyone's finding or beating it without a computer.)
[Sorry about the deleted comments on the way to this one,
 if you were notified of them.]

Comment: Well, @Rubio, a base 10 system has 10 digits (0 through 9), a base 8 system has 8 digits (0 through 7) ...and in the same manner..A base 2 system has two digits 0 and 1 ...And hence a base 1 system should have only one digit and it should be '0'...:-), though it does not make sense...As such unary systems...are complemented by something which represents 'absence of any' or 'presence of nothing' by '0'. Hence 0 and 1 should form the digits in an unary system. Anyways, these are my own views which may...be inline or out of line with others.

Comment: @humn Hi, is a bounty announced on this or not yet  ? I have a solution ready with 4 digits and less than or equal to 40 times the used numbers counted. :-)

Comment: @humn, I have added my 2nd solution below my first one. Please check it.

Comment: Err...the 2nd one got  slipped...through checks...Need to get a different one @humn...Thanks Rubio!

Comment: Fractional bases are certainly welcome here, Mea Culpa Nay, wow!
(One of my 43-count solutions uses a single fractional base,
 and you went and found a much smaller solution that uses two.)
You have such a refreshing feel for this puzzle.
A bounty is on the way, partly as a bribe
for you to add brief mentions of how you came up with these solutions.
Too bad about 2 vs 3 in the previous solution
that included a perfect ${\small 10}_{10} \, \small .$
[And sorry about the multiple versions of this comment.]

Comment: @humn, thanks for the bounty ! Well, solutions ... though involved trial and error, but as you told intuition also played a role in this. For example, thinking over a while suggests that the choice of 4 digits (based on which P,Q,R and S can be arrived at) decides M and N. Also, instead of incrementing by one, doubling / doubling and and then subtracting one patterns proved to be helpful while selecting M and N, though the actual/intended solution which is 4 digits based and uses less than 43 times of usage of digits still illudes me :-).

Comment: Thank you for more than one reason to bounty, Mea Culpa Nay.
Care to add the bulk of your latest comment (or something like it)
to the solution post itself?
Perhaps even include what each solution looked like midway.
These kinds of notes could just be added recklessly to the end of the post as
something like "Addendum. Unedited notes and worksheets."
Not to reap 1000s of points from this puzzle's limited audience
but to broaden the imaginations
of current and future members of that audience.
Your solutions are spectacularly mystifying examples of
`lateral-thinking`!

Comment: Today's solution gets the
$\color{#0c0}{\large\raise-.1ex\checkmark}\kern-.3em$,
Mea Culpa Nay, right on!
It's not the absolutely minimal solution,
which was found with a computer,
but it _is_ exquisitely neat
and, I hope, the minimum that anyone would find by hand.
By the way, I'd still like to see added to your answer
hints at how you came up with the first two fantastic solutions.

Answer (score 2):

After being told I misread the question, *again*, and that 4 digits was a requirement, not a max, I'm modifying my solution as explained below.  The new new solution with 73 digits is:

> M = 203, N = 23
>  P, Q, R, S and T are all the square of the previous value.  Something as simple as 10 has all its powers use the same 2 digits, and fit within the parameters, resulting in 4 total distinct  digits.
>  P = 10 = 1E1, Q=100=1E2, R=1E4, S=1E8, and T=1E16.  That should yield 49 total zeros, and 8 ones, 8 twos and 8 threes, meaning 73 total digits.

Below was what I wrote when I thought that the solution was based on a max of 4 digits:

After being told I totally misread the problem, I have *totally new* solution.  It uses 73 total digits (only 2 distinct digits).  I think it's possible to narrow that down, but it probably involves something interesting with storing P-T in non-base 10, or using symbols that represent digits higher than 9.

> M = 100, N = 10
>  P, Q, R, S and T are all the square of the previous value.  Something as simple as 10 has all its powers use less then 4 digits, and fit within the parameters, 
>  P = 10 = 1E1, Q=100=1E2, R=1E4, S=1E8, and T=1E16.  That should yield 57 total zeros, and 16 ones, meaning 73 total digits.

Comment: Looks like you solved a different puzzle!  Not bad.
(Might be worth posting it separately. I'd like to see it.)
But your approach looks promising for this puzzle too.
The way your solution lays out according to this puzzle
matches my best hand-figured 32 total digits
(most values get counted twice or more),
and the first line of $\small M_{_P}=N_{_Q}$ comes out $\small 55_{35} = 54_{40}$,
which works out to an untrue $\small 180 \ne 204$
according the rules here.

Comment: Sorry, totally misunderstood the problem.  Putting a new solution in.

Comment: Well, @Jesse, the proposed solution **must**use 4 different digits. Your solution uses only 2!. Please check.

Comment: And now you solved the original version of this puzzle, [_New Mathematics forever_](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51782/new-mathematics-forever), Jesse! That's actually a more clever solution than for this one,
which is why this version asks for 4 different digits and has a qualitatively different solution.

Comment: @humn a solution that requires 4 different digits (thought that was a max), is trivially generated from my solution.  Multiplying M and N by 2 and adding 3 to each will keep the same bases, the same total digits and will get us to 4 digits.  Will modify solution to match.

Comment: Oops, the comment above should be also directed @MeaCulpaNay

Comment: When calculating the number of digits I think you have to take into account the fact that M and N occur four times and Q R and S occur twice.

Comment: Beautiful 4-different-digit adaptation, which can continue infinitely!
And nicely derived.
(I really enjoy how this puzzle has so many surprises.)
Incidentally, my total-digits count for this latest solution
comes out 73 (49 0s, 8 1s, 8 2s, 8 3s)
but this solution will get the next bounty
when the system allows and I log in again.
If you don't mind, Jesse,
I'd like to sometime edit/add a tabular display to this solution.

Comment: good catch by @2012rcampion on 5th Aug. 2017, though that was what explained by humn in the original problem posted.

Answer (score 2):

> M = 121, N = 100, P = 10, Q = 11, R = 12, S = 13, T = 14

I know this solution uses 5 digits (a total of 40 digits), but that was a quick manual find.