# Five Apples from Moscow Puzzles

Tags: lateral-thinking

Five apples are there in a basket.How do you divide them among five girls so that each girl gets an apple,but one apple remains in the basket?

Comment: This puzzle was coincidentally used as an example in [_How to choose the best answer in puzzles?_](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27729/how-to-choose-the-best-answer-in-puzzles)

Comment: Logic deduction and lateral thinking are, I believe, complete opposites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> One of the girls gets the basket as well.